# Timezone setting while integration between Google adwords and Salesforce sales cloud

Tags: google-ads, crm

We've integrated Google AdWords accounts with Salesforce sales cloud account to track lead creation & conversion data based on the GCLID values.

Currently, the date format in salesforce is GMT+0:00 while my local time zone is (date+05:30). When data get synced between adwords and google, this data (in GMT+0:00) time zone is being stored as it is i.e. 5:00 PM GMT+0:00 will be stored as 5 PM only. Because of this in few cases I'm getting the error "conversion action cannot precede the click."

How can I control time zone while syncing data between adwords and google through standard connector.